# what is the difference between String.Concat ,string.format and +?

Tags: c#, .net, string, c#-4.0

What is difference between:

- `String.Concat`,
- `String.Format`,
- `+` operator.

which one is more efficient in every condition whether long or short string concatenation.

Answer (score 14):

`string.Concat` *just* concatenates strings together. It provides no conversions beyond calling `ToString`, no formatting etc.

`string.Format` is a much richer, allowing format patterns etc.

When you use the `+` operator in C# source code, the compiler converts that into calls to `String.Concat` - it's not an execution time operator in the way that it is in, say, `decimal`.

So this:

```
string result = x + y + z;
```

is compiled into this:

```
string result = string.Concat(x, y, z);
```

In terms of efficiency, clearly calls to `string.Concat` and using `+` can be equivalent. I'd generally expect that to be faster than `string.Format` *but the difference would be negligible in most cases*. You should write the clearest, most maintainable code you can first (which often means using `string.Format`) and then micro-optimize only when you have test data to show that you *need* to optimize that particular piece, and then only retain the optimization once you've proved it helps.

Note that one area where a bit of optimization *can* make a huge difference is *repeated* concatenation, usually in a loop. This code is horribly inefficient:

```
string result = "";
foreach (var x in y)
{
    // Do some processing...
    string z = ...;
    result += z;
}
```

This ends up having to copy an intermediate string on each iteration. In these situations, *either* use `StringBuilder`, or use a LINQ query to represent the items you'll end up needing to concatenate and then either `string.Join` or `string.Concat` to perform the concatenation.

Comment: It's possibly worth pointing out that the performance difference (albeit possibly negligible, as Jon points out) is because under the hood, `String.Format` instantiates a `StringBuilder` to do the work, whereas `String.Concat` (and `+`, presumably, then) uses `unsafe` string manipulation in memory.

Comment: @OwenBlacker: I wouldn't want to assume it's because of that. Fundamentally it's doing more work - it's got to parse the format string for one thing.

Comment: @JonSkeet: Indeed, I would expect the parsing to be the difference. I merely found the under-the-hood difference to be intriguing when I first thought to run mscorlib through Reflector, so thought other SO users might be similarly intrigued :o)