# String.Concat Vs String.Join in C#

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core

Under what circumstances would I prefer `String.Concat` to `String.Join` in C#?

`String.Join` seems to be able to do what `Concat` does and more i.e. most times one would need a separator and `String.Join` provides a nice API for scenarios like this.

Is `String.Concat` just a slightly more convenient API for situations where a separator is not required?

Comment: @Dai why did you close this as a duplicate of a Java question?

Comment: @Sweeper Carelessless on my part - I meant to close it as a dupe of this one: (I don't know why SO suggested a Java-tagged question...) https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9289284/what-is-the-difference-between-string-concat-string-format-and

Comment: @Dai not exactly what the user asks. The comparison is with Join, which there's not in the answers you marked as duplicates.

Comment: @MarioVernari Yeah, fair - I'm actually surprised there's no exact dupes... Reopening now.

Comment: Concat predates Join. And there is no way to overload Concat so that it has the same API as Join.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you compare the sources of the two methods (let's take a comparable signature), you'll realize that the code is practically the same. The only difference is the separator insertion.

[string Concat(IEnumerable<string?> values)](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs,206408f6325aea24)

[string Join(string? separator, IEnumerable<string?> values)](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs,fa961ce440526a4d)

That is, with a null or empty separator, the two methods behave exactly the same (and also with the same performance).

However, it seems that's a fortunate case. If we take those overloads:

[string Concat(params object?[] args)](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs,40825b9a6e8f4b1e)

[string Join(string? separator, params object?[] values)](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/src/libraries/System.Private.CoreLib/src/System/String.Manipulation.cs,815fed0ee06a7bc8)

the first implementation is unexpectedly complicated than the second one. I alsu suspect that's much slower than the `Join`.

Sounds like a legacy code which should be rewritten.